# Найти слово с помощью grep, sed, awk

Tags: bash, sed, grep, awk

Есть рандомный текст, в нем встречаются

```
"user":"Blabla_123" ...... "user":"123_Blabla"....
```

Как нам получить

```
Blabla_123

123_Blabla
```

Есть код, он не работает

```
grep "user" путь к фаилу | awk -F ':"' '{print $2}'
```

Буду рад любым ответам, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я предполагаю, что в файле одна строка?  В таком случае, вот вариант
с *GNU grep* и *POSIX sed*:

```sh
$ grep -e '"user":"[^"]\+"' -o ./file.txt |\
    sed -e 's/.*"user":"\([^"]\+\)".*/\1/g'
```

Вариант только через *POSIX* чуть посложней:

```sh
$ sed -e 's/"user":"[^"]\+"/\0\n/' ./file.txt |\
    sed -e 's/.*"user":"\([^"]\+\)".*/\1/g'
```

Вариант с *POSIX cut* в конце от @0andriy:

```sh
$ sed -e 's/"user":"[^"]\+"/\0\n/' ./file.txt | cut -d '"' -f 4
```

Comment: Ты просто ТОП, Спасибо!! 
'Не смог избежать комментария в стиль "Спасибо"'
Очень помог!!!!!

Comment: Второй `sed` можно сменить на более легковесный `cut`.

Comment: @0andriy  Добавил.